# How to search from the position where the cursor is at the moment?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi 11. I don't know what i changed on the IDE, but now everytime i use the search feature (CTRL+F), it will search starting from the first line of current unit.

For instance, if i'm on line 1000, i want to search from this line on, not going back to the first line.

It was working correctly until last week. I tried to find an option to set it back to the way it was, but could not find !

Please, where is this option that i can't find ? :-0

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, Clipbrd, Strutils,
  Buttons, Mask, Shellapi, Spin, ImgList, AppEvnts, Menus, Dateutils, CheckLst,
  Tlhelp32, Registry, ShlObj, DB, DBClient, WebHousC, Sndkey32, DBGrids, Series, TeEngine,
  TeeProcs, Chart, Grids, uCEFChromium, uCEFInterfaces, uCEFTypes, uCEFApplication,
  uCEFChromiumCore, VclTee.TeeGDIPlus, System.ImageList, Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg, Midaslib, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg, Vcl.FileCtrl, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.MPlayer;
```

Comment: Maybe you have checked the **Entire scope** checkbox in the search panel? Also, there's an IDE bug that makes this checkbox sometimes invisible. I believe restarting the IDE fixes that.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Bingo ! It was invisible ! Thank you a lot, please post as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have accidentally checked the **Entire scope** checkbox in the search panel.

Also, there's an IDE bug that makes this checkbox sometimes invisible. I believe restarting the IDE fixes that.